# Invalid argument value of 0 is not valid for index

Tags: c#, xml, listview

I have a listView, and when I select other value from the listview, it gives an error

`invalid argument value of 0 is not valid for index`

The code is this:

```
UserList = getUsers();            
for (int i = 0; i < UserList.Count; i++)
        {
            User user = UserList.ElementAt(i);

            ListViewItem row = new ListViewItem();
            row.Text = user.name.ToString();
            row.SubItems.Add(user.surname);
            row.Tag = user.weight.ToString();
            row.Tag = user.height.ToString();
            row.Tag = user.id;

            listView1.Items.Add(row);
        }
```

userList is a list from xml file:

```
    public List<User> getUsers()
    {
        XmlNodeList nodes = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/users/user");

        foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
        {
            User user = new User();
            user.id = Convert.ToInt32(node.SelectSingleNode("id").InnerText);
            user.name = node.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText;
            user.surname = node.SelectSingleNode("surname").InnerText;
            user.weight = Convert.ToInt32(node.SelectSingleNode("weight").InnerText);
            user.height = Convert.ToInt32(node.SelectSingleNode("height").InnerText);

            UserList.Add(user);
        }

        return UserList;
    }
```

How can I get rid of the error?

--EDIT:

it gives an error here:

```
public List<UserData> getAllUsers()
{
    var id = (int)listView1.SelectedItems[0].Tag; // ERROR in this line
    var currenTask = UserList.Where(t => t.id == id).First();
    SqlConnection conn = Program.getConnection;
    SqlDataReader rdr = null;
    try
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM personalData where user_id = @user_id";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        SqlParameter user_id = cmd.Parameters.Add("@user_id", SqlDbType.Int);
        user_id.Value = currenTask.id;
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            UserData userData = new UserData();

            userData.id = rdr.GetInt32(0);
            userData.mode = rdr.GetString(1);
            userData.time_preview = rdr.GetString(2);
            userData.time = rdr.GetInt32(3);
            userData.callories_lost = rdr.GetDouble(4);
            userData.date = rdr.GetDateTime(5);
            userData.user_id = rdr.GetInt32(6);

            userData = userData.createUser(userData.id, userData.mode, userData.time_preview, userData.time, userData.callories_lost, userData.date, userData.user_id);
            UserDataList.Add(userData);

        }
        rdr.Close();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (rdr != null) { rdr.Close(); }
        if (conn != null) { conn.Close(); }
    }
    return UserDataList;
}
```

the error is in the comment

Answer (score 0):

What if there are no users? Your loop will still run because 0 is not less than 0.

Use `<=` instead of `<`.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= UserList.Count; i++)
```

Comment: error: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Comment: Does your UserList have elements?

Comment: when i click on the exe (debug and release), it appears popup window: Form 1 Error.......

Comment: You should run this in the VS debugger and let it break on the exception, then examine the variables to see what's up. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10392501/279516.